# Напишите способ в Ubuntu 14.04 принимать информацию о USB подключениях новых, без пингования lsusb (тормозов)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

Напишите способ в Ubuntu 14.04 принимать информацию о SB подключениях  новых, без пингования lsusb (тормозов)?

Comment: пожалуйста: `$ udevadm`

Comment: Тормозов и программ без пингования

Answer (score 2):

Monitor Device Events in Linux

```
udevadm monitor
```